# V-Select enviar dados para backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tenho um SelectList em Vue.Js e preciso capturar dados dos itens como title, id, description, porém não estou conseguindo pegar estes dados vindos da API (dentro de um array).
Preciso enviar além do campo nome (único que está indo), os demais dados acima.

É possível enviar para o backend (Laravel) gravar no banco mais de um dado ou somente os item-text e ou item-label (não aplicados neste caso)?
Obrigado

```
    <v-select
       name="pacote"
       label="title"
       :key="'pacote-field'"
       :value="entry.pacote"
       :options="pacotes"
       :closeOnSelect="false"
        multiple
        @input="updatePacote"
        @search.focus="focusField('pacote')"
        @search.blur="clearFocus"
     />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução 1**

Se você está utilizando o `vuetify` você pode utilizar a propriedade `return-object` para que o select retorno todo o objeto selecionado.

Exemplo [aqui](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEBRVb?&editors=101).

Baseado [nesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962953/how-to-get-selected-value-from-dropdown-in-vuejs) resposta do stackoverflow.

**Solução 2**

Se você está usando `vue` puro você pode passar a propriedade `value` com o valor do objecto ao criar o select.

exemplo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [{
        value: '1',
        bankName: 'Bank1'
      },
      {
        value: '2',
        bankName: 'Bank2'
      },
    ],
    selectedBank: null
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedBank">
    <option v-for="item in items" :value="item">
      {{ item.bankName }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <div>
    {{selectedBank}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Opa, mas ai voce está definindo os items, e minha fonte é uma API externa, eu teria que trazer tudo pra dentro do data/items para depois mostrar no select? Vi vários exemplos desta forma, o que não acho prático, pois listar tudo isso em código não faz muito sentido. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Apenas para o exemplo eu listei tudo no `data`. O ideal é que você mantenha isso em um gerenciador de estados da aplicação como o `vuex` ou o `pinia` e enviasse isso para o componente via `props` ou `computed` .